# How to decode the DICOM files based transfer syntax JPEG Baseline(Process 1)?

Tags: python, jpeg

here is the code：

```
import pydicom
dataset = pydicom.read_file('xxx') # a dicom file
print(dataset.pixel_array) # the dataset.pixel_array exits
```

here is the problem:

```
NotImplementedError: NO available image handler could decode this transfer syntax JPEG Baseline(Process 1)
```

Now I hope to get the pixel_array so that I can continue my work, but I have not receive a good solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's verey low quality, is not clear about the question, does not present a solvable problem and so on

Comment: Post your code as formatted text, not as images! (the OP tried to add *empty text* links to external images)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of code are absolutely useless here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons they should not be used. Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post and properly formatted. Please do so. Also, when you created your account here it was suggested that you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages. Please do that as well, especially [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: The same applies to the traceback, post it as text as well.

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not reason the pydicom library. I have meet this in Windows System. When I use Ubuntu, it does not exists.